# Vue.js - Element UI - HTML message in MessageBox

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using `vue-js 2.3` and `element-ui`. This question is more specific to the `MessageBox` component for which you can find the documentation [here](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/message-box)

#### Problem

I'd like to be able to enter `html` message in the `MessageBox`
More specifically I would like to display the data contained in `dataForMessage` by using a `v-for` loop.

Apparently, we can insert `vnode` in the message but I have no idea where to find some information about the syntax.

https://jsfiddle.net/7ugahcfz/

```
var Main = {
   data:function () {
   return {
    dataForMessage: [
     {
        name:'Paul',
        gender:'Male',
      },
      {
        name:'Anna',
        gender:'Female',
      },
    ],
   }
   },
    methods: {
      open() {
        const h = this.$createElement;
        this.$msgbox({
          title: 'Message',
          message: h('p', null, [
            h('span', null, 'Message can be '),
            h('i', { style: 'color: teal' }, 'VNode '),
            h('span', null, 'but I would like to see the data from '),
             h('i', { style: 'color: teal' }, 'dataForMessage'),
          ])
        }).then(action => {
        });
      },
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the HTML layout you want? https://jsfiddle.net/7ugahcfz/1/

Comment: Also, this is the documentation for createElement. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments

Comment: I updated this fiddle to give you an example of the HTML I'd like. https://jsfiddle.net/cdznvxvb/. My problem is more that I don't know how to use a variable and loop over with the `vnode` syntax. Basically I would like to open a `confirm dialog` and be able to display any data I wish to by looping through them

Comment: Maybe you can use "Dialog" instead : http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
methods: {
  open() {
    const h = this.$createElement;
    let people = this.dataForMessage.map(p => h('li', `${p.name} ${p.gender}`))
    const message = h('div', null, [
      h('h1', "Model wished"),
      h('div', "The data contained in dataForMessage are:"),
      h('ul', people)
    ])
    this.$msgbox({
      title: 'Message',
      message
    }).then(action => {
    });
  },
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/cdznvxvb/2/).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Once again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use html directly and convert to vnodes by using domProps:

```
const html = '<div><h1>Model wished</h1><div>The data contained in dataForMessage are:</div><ul><li>Paul Male</li><li>Anna Female</li></ul></div>'
const message = h("div", {domProps:{innerHTML: html}})
```

(The above is simplified without the loop. Just to get the idea)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bz1ertpy/)